# Check if word from file1 one exist in file2

Tags: php, perl, bash, compare

I have two files.
file1.txt contains:

```
hello
world
france
```

file2.txt contains:

```
hello
germany
france
```

I am trying to figure out how can obtain that word `germany` doesn't exist in file1.txt

In any language

Comment: What about the lack of the word "world" from file1 in file2?  your question text doesn't match your example.

Comment: in php, use file_get_content() and convrt them to array using explode() and then compare using if-else statement and other

Comment: This works in PHP: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36226078/3179492

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`comm`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/comm)

```
comm -13 <(sort -u /tmp/list1) <(sort -u /tmp/list2)
```

Comment: I don't need the difference between both files. I need exactly as in my example

Comment: comm only works for **sorted** files

Comment: comm -13 <(sort -u /tmp/list1) <(sort -u /tmp/list2)

Comment: That would sort it on the fly, without actually "really" sorting the files physically...

Comment: @PaulCalabro it works, however sorting is not necessary for this question.

Comment: Try it out! It should demonstrate that Germany doesn't exist in file1.txt :)

Comment: @user2023424  Your example is the opposite of the text in your question's subject.  You have text in both files that are unique.  Did you reverse the names of file1 and file2 accidentally?  Or do you really mean to identify "world" as the strange piece of text, like your subject text implies?

Answer (score 0):

Perl:

```
++$file1{$_} while <$fh1>;
while (<$fh2>) {
    print if !$file1{$_};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this short line should work for you:

```
 grep -Fwvf file1 file2
```

or a longer line:

```
 awk 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next}!($0 in a)' file1 file2
```

both commands output:

```
germany
```