# Remove line of file1 that exist on file2

Tags: php

I want remove all line present on FILE1 from the FILE2.

I tried using this code, but didn't succeeded:

*The function:*

```
function removeit($searchfor, $file) {
   $file1 = fopen($file, "r") or exit("Unable to openfile!");
   $t="";
   while(!feof($file1)) {
      $k= fgets($file1);
      $pattern = preg_quote($searchfor, '/');
      $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
      if ( preg_match($pattern, $k))
      {}
      else {
         $t=$t.$k;
      }
   }

   fclose($file1);
   $file = fopen($file, "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($file,$t);
   fclose($file);
}
```

*The code that do the job:*

```
$file = fopen("file1.txt", "r");
while(!feof($file)) {
   $line = fgets($file);
   # do same stuff with the $line
   echo removeit(trim($line), 'file2.txt');
}
fclose($file);
```

Please any fix for this code ? or do you have any other method to do this job properly ?
I tried all sort of code in order to get the proper result, but all what i tried was not succeeded.

The lines of FILE1 present on FILE2 not contained on a full line !

***Here an example:***

*FILE1:*

```
AAA
BBB
CCC
DDD
```

*And here FILE2:*

```
555AAAPPP // This line contain AAA line1 of FILE1 (To remove)
MMMBBBEEE // This contain BBB (To remove)
111CCC333 // This contain CCC (To remove)
DD15568 // This line will not be removed because not present on FILE1
```

And the code must let the code stay like it was before, only lines must be removed.

Comment: Your question is unclear to me: you want `555AAAPPP` to be removed or not?

Comment: Yes, all the three lines must be removed because it contain lines of FILE1 :)

Comment: Erk, please don't do this: `$file = fopen($file, "w")` -- You're changing the type of the variable. Instead use something like `$filename` for the string and `$file` for the handle. It's confusing.

Comment: Incidentally, you can simplify that regexp to be just `$pattern = "/"+$pattern+"/";`. `^.*` and `.*$` are basically no-ops. (And ugh, you're doing it again.)

Comment: Wait. What is preg_quote() supposed to be doing?

I think you're ending up with a match pattern that looks like this:

`/^.*555AAAPPP \/\/ This line contain AAA line1 of FILE1 (remove).*$/`

Get those comments out of the FILE2 and ditch the preg_quote call.

Comment: I did that, but nothing solved ! any other solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
var_dump( CheckForMatches::run( "FILE1", "FILE2" ) );

class CheckForMatches
{
    private static $arrayBasePatterns;
    private static $arrayScanFile;

    public static function run( $baseFile, $targetFile )
    {
        self::$arrayBasePatterns = file( $baseFile,   FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );
        self::$arrayScanFile     = file( $targetFile, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES );

        $cleanedResult = array_filter( self::$arrayScanFile, 
                                       "CheckForMatches::arrayCallback" );
        return $cleanedResult;
    }

    public static function arrayCallback( $arrayElement )
    {
        foreach ( self::$arrayBasePatterns as $basePattern )
        {
            if ( strpos( $arrayElement, $basePattern ) !== FALSE )
            {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
}
```